# Errors in Visual studio 2013

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

What version of mySQL for VS, Connector, Workbench, and server must I install when using VS 2013? I currently use mySQL for VS version 1.2.8. I can establish a connection with VS but cannot connect to the database or datasets

Comment: Can you use a newer version of VS? Finding support for such an old version will be difficult.

Comment: I cant its for school work